# if nameTextField.text!.isEmpty not working?

Tags: swift

Im trying to check if a `textField`is empty, and if it is a popup should show:

```
func missingText (title: String, message: String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)


        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

 @IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


            //Display errormsg for missing entry
            if nameTextField.text!.isEmpty
            {

                missingText(title: "Error", message: "Missing name")
            }    
}
```

Nothing is happening when the textfield is empty. I (think) I have the exact same code in another app, and that's working fine.. What am I missing?
The `nameTextField`is hooked up.

Comment: you are adding `textField` in alert?

Comment: Check your `IBAction` is connected with `UIButton` in interface

Comment: Keep a breakpoint at `if nameTextField.text!.isEmpty` and check if it is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem once, It turned out that instead of using the `placeholder` for description for the textfield, I used the `Text`. Both are located in Attributes inspector for the `textField`. So, if u use the `Text`for description, the `textField` will never be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I guess textfield text is nil. so that it may not be calling. try with below code

```
@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


    guard let text = textField.text, text != "" else{
        missingText(title: "Error", message: "Missing name")
        return
    }

    //  do stuff with text,
}
```

Comment: You ca also use !text.isEmpty instead of text != ""

Answer (score 0):

[image]

u can try this one this might will help you . nametextfield.text , !text.empty